# Blank line at the end when writing into csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.6

I have to write in a CSV file several times a day. When I launch the script to write again into it, there is a blank line between the last line and the new line. 
I don't think it's in the text I wrote, as there is no blank line between the lines written in the same session. How to avoid that ? Thanks

```
csvTwitter = open("twitterDB.csv", 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
wr = csv.writer(csvTwitter, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
listeInfosTweet = [tweet['id'],tweet['timestamp_ms'],tweet['created_at'],tweet['user']['name'],tweet['user']['location'],tweet['user']['followers_count'],texteTweet,tweet['lang']]
wr.writerow(listeInfosTweet)
```

Answer (score 1):

I run the same condition code by python3 three times, it doesn't reproduce your issue.

```
import csv


csvFile = open("./test.csv", 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(['number', 'number plus 2', 'number times 2'])
    for i in range(10):
        writer.writerow([i, i+2, i*2])
finally:
    csvFile.close()
```

This example is from book《Web Scraping with Python: Collecting Data from the Modern Web》.
Maybe it caused by your data source?

OUT:

```
"number","number plus 2","number times 2"
"0","2","0"
"1","3","2"
"2","4","4"
"3","5","6"
"4","6","8"
"5","7","10"
"6","8","12"
"7","9","14"
"8","10","16"
"9","11","18"
"number","number plus 2","number times 2"
"0","2","0"
"1","3","2"
"2","4","4"
"3","5","6"
"4","6","8"
"5","7","10"
"6","8","12"
"7","9","14"
"8","10","16"
"9","11","18"
"number","number plus 2","number times 2"
"0","2","0"
"1","3","2"
"2","4","4"
"3","5","6"
"4","6","8"
"5","7","10"
"6","8","12"
"7","9","14"
"8","10","16"
"9","11","18"
```

Comment: This script also works fine for me, weird. Thanks for trying, i'll update the post if i found something !